# Ternary Operation on Files (nio/Java 7)

Tags: java, nio

I need to create a tempFile. But before I create it, I need to check it if `Path` exists using `Files`. I am able to achieve it using below:

```
    Path docName;
    try {
        if (Files.exists(docName)) {
            Files.delete(docName);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        docName = Files.createFile(docName);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException ignoreit) {
    }
```

Wondering if there is a way to minimize above using Java 7+ APIs. An elegant way of doing it, I mean to say.

Say for example, using Ternary operator if I try for below:

```
????  result = Files.exists(docName) ? Files.delete(docName) : Files.createFile(docName);
```

**Question:** What (data-type) should I put in place of `????` ?

Comment: Data types notwithstanding, your ternary is not logically equivalent to the long-form code.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce it?

Comment: You could get some reduction of the first part by using `Files.deleteIfExists()`.

Comment: From the original code, it looks like you want to overwrite the file with new content.  So I would simply go with a "write" operation with the option to overwrite.  I understand this because you create the file anyway.  you delete only if exists.  so you intend the file will be there in any case.

Comment: Maybe, @PamStums.  Deleting an existing file and recreating it may result in the new file having different ownership or mode.  It will definitely result in the new file having a different creation time.  These may be wanted effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, a ternary expression would work only if both branches return the same (or compatible) types, and it's not the same as your other code.  `delete()` returns void while `create()` returns a `Path`.

```
try {
    if (Files.exists(docPath))
        Files.delete(docPath);
    docPath = Files.create(docPath)
}
catch...
```

Comment: How about: `Files.deleteIfExists(docPath);  docPath = Files.create(docPath);`